# Is space more contracted than time is dilated near a massive object?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

Being near a massive object causes an elevation in the 5th dimension axis such that time travels at an inclination (the time axis is at a downward angle) and therefore travels through less time than a reference frame in flat spacetime.

It also causes 3D space to contract, and in order to be considered contracted it would have to travel more space at a certain speed than you would in flat spacetime.

Surely this means that the effect of contraction must be more significant than time dilation, because time dilation would naturally cause space dilation (because it travels diagonally and downward rather than just diagonally in warped spacetime, therefore covering space more slowly), therefore it needs to be more significant because it needs to counter this dilation, which would make it equivalent to the distance travelled in flat spacetime despite travelling diagonally and downwards, but then it needs to contract even more for in order to for the diagonal down motion to be quicker through space than a reference frame in flat spacetime.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that General Relativity involves a 5th dimension? Or that time “travels”?

Answer (score 3):

> Being near a massive object causes an elevation in the 5th dimension axis such that time travels at an inclination (the time axis is at a downward angle) and therefore travels through less time than a reference frame in flat spacetime.

Not sure where you got this interpretation. This is just wrong.

> It also causes 3D space to contract,

No, general relativity describes gravity as *curvature* of spacetime, not contraction of space.